# sql server script generater stored proc

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

anyone know of such stored procs to generate scripts for tables/indexex/views/sp's etc.

Comment: You mean like Sql Server Management Studio?

Comment: yup but not from the gui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GUI (SQL Server Management Studio) is just a thin shell around the SMO. All the scripting power is inside the SMO. Use the [Scripter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scripter.aspx) class. Have a look at this basic intro to SMO scripting: [SQL Server: SMO Scripting Basics](http://blogs.msdn.com/mwories/archive/2005/05/07/basic-scripting.aspx).

Comment: Sweet. Never saw that before.

Answer (score 0):

Views and SPs are relatively easy since the code is in the syscomments/INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES.

I've created one for tables, but it's not particularly complete - and in fact, it only actually generates the appropriate CREATE TABLE statement for a completely different platform - Teradata, so it turns the PRIMARY KEY into a UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX (Teradata allows both a PRIMARY KEY and a PRIMARY INDEX, but does not allow the PRIMARY KEY - or any index - to have the same columns as any other index).

I'm not sure there are any standard ones out there, but it would just be a matter of all the little things - getting all the extended properties on columns tables and indexes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any stored procs for this but Microsoft has the [SQL Server Database Publishing Wizard](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=56E5B1C5-BF17-42E0-A410-371A838E570A&displaylang=en) to generate scripts (structure and data).